# How to run while loop with background worker without freezing UI screen in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am working on a WPF application where I need to run another process ("ABC") (long process with lots of multi threading and parallel processing) inside simple method of START and STOP. So when I click on START I need to run the process "ABC" continuously until I click on STOP. In process "ABC" I have to make use of parallel processing and multi threading a lot, so when the while loop for process "ABC" is running, the UI screen freezes. I need it to run freely. The loop is running very well but UI side screen becomes frozen.

My expectation is to run process "ABC" in loop until it get STOP. Right now I am running its loop using background worker. It's running very well, but it's freezing the UI screen. So I want to run UI and process freely without freezing.

I have try below code :

```
private async void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (((App)Application.Current).IsStrategyRunning == true)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    CriteriaSections.PhantomEntrance phantomEntrance = new CriteriaSections.PhantomEntrance();
                    phantomEntrance.startPhantomEntranceEvaluation();
                });
            }
        }
```

but it's freezing. Please can you give me suggestion for this ?
Thank you.

I am calling BackgroundWorker1_DoWork using below code :

```
private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker BackgroundWorker1;
 this.BackgroundWorker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
                this.BackgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.BackgroundWorker1_DoWork);
                BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

while startPhantomEntranceEvaluation process like below

```
public void startPhantomEntranceEvaluation()
        {
            try
            {
                if (((App)Application.Current).IsStrategyRunning == true)
                {
                    PhantomEntrance phantomEntrance = new PhantomEntrance();
                    string script = parseCriteriaLines.parseCriteiraLines(phantomEntrance.txtScriptArea.Text);
                    if (script.Length > 2)
                    {
                        PhantomEntranceCriteria(script, triggerScript, rbTrue.IsChecked.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogHandling.printErrorLog(ex.ToString(), "PhantomEntrance->startPhantomEntranceEvaluation");
            }
        }
```

and related to it further process is like below

```
public static void PhantomEntranceCriteria(string script, string triggerScript, bool triggerStatus)
        {
            double simpleGain = 0;
            try
            {
                var builder = new StringBuilder();
                var symbolList = StrategyDetailsAndList.symbolListFromFile;

                var taskArray = new List<Task>();

                var lstsymbolWithRanking = symbolListWithRanking(symbolList);
                symbolListWithPosition = lstsymbolWithRanking.ToDictionary(x => x, y => true);

                foreach (var symbol in symbolListWithPosition.Where(x => x.Value == true).ToList())
                {
                        phantomEntranceResult = criteriaEvalution.Evaluate(script, false, new List<parseObj>(), ref builder, symbol.Key, "Phantom Entrance Criteria");
                        if (phantomEntranceResult.Values.FirstOrDefault() == true)
                        {
                            lock (_lock)
                            {
                                #region fake position
                                List<parseObj> tempList = phantomEntranceResult.SelectMany(q => q.Key).ToList();
                                var x = phantomEntranceResult.Keys;

                                var askprice = x.Select(q => q.Where(z => z.VariableName == "ASKPRICE()").Select(a => a.Value).FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();
                                var symbolName = x.Select(q => q.Select(z => z.symbolName).FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();
                                var currentAskPrice = PolygonSocket.SocketConnection.liveQuotesList.Where(q => q.sym == symbolName).Select(q => q.ap).LastOrDefault();
                                var currentBidPrice = PolygonSocket.SocketConnection.liveQuotesList.Where(q => q.sym == symbolName).Select(q => q.bp).LastOrDefault();
                                var currentTradePrice = PolygonSocket.SocketConnection.liveTradeList.Where(q => q.sym == symbolName).Select(q => q.p).LastOrDefault();
                                var currentTradeVolume = PolygonSocket.SocketConnection.liveTradeList.Where(q => q.sym == symbolName && q.t > (q.t - 1 * 60 * 1000)).Sum(q => q.s);

                                simpleGain = (((currentBidPrice / x.Select(q => q.Where(z => z.VariableName == "ASKPRICE()").Select(a => a.Value).FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault()) - 1) * 5000);

                                var pctGain = (((currentBidPrice / x.Select(q => q.Where(z => z.VariableName == "ASKPRICE()").Select(a => a.Value).FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault()) - 1) * 100);

                                var currentAskPrice_result = new parseObj("CURRANTASKPRICE", currentAskPrice, true, symbolName);
                                var currentBidPrice_result = new parseObj("CURRENTBIDPRICE", currentBidPrice, true, symbolName);
                                var currentTradePrice_result = new parseObj("CURRENTTRADEPRICE", currentTradePrice, true, symbolName);
                                var currentTradeVolume_result = new parseObj("CURRENTTRADEVOLUME", currentTradeVolume, true, symbolName);

                                var simpleGain_result = new parseObj("GAIN", simpleGain, true, symbolName);
                                var pctGain_result = new parseObj("PCTGAIN", pctGain, true, symbolName);

                                tempList.Add(currentBidPrice_result);
                                tempList.Add(currentAskPrice_result);
                                tempList.Add(currentTradePrice_result);
                                tempList.Add(currentTradeVolume_result);
                                tempList.Add(simpleGain_result);
                                tempList.Add(pctGain_result);

                                printFakePosition(tempList, symbolName, true, "Phantom Entrance Fake Position");

                                try
                                {
                                    tempFakePositionList.Add(symbolName, tempList);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {

                                }
                                #endregion
                            }
                            parallelScripts.pExitWithEntrance(phantomEntranceResult);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //MessageBox.Show("Phantom Entrance become false");
                        }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogHandling.printErrorLog(ex.ToString(), "PhantomEntrance->PhantomEntranceCriteria");
            }
        }
```

while in above code `parallelScripts.pExitWithEntrance(phantomEntranceResult);` also contains lots of process like above. And in sub there are nearby 14 xaml pages which are connected to each other and depend on each other for perform action. Where I have use another dispatcher.invoke, background worker, and parallel processing.

Comment: Show the call to `BackgroundWorker1_DoWork`

Comment: You are executing the whole body of the loop on the UI thread via `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Only use `Dispatcher.Invoke`on the few places where you immediately interact with the user interface.

Comment: what's inside 'startPhantomEntranceEvaluation'?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, I have edit from where I am calling BackgroundWorker1_DoWork. Please can you guide more ?

Comment: @d.moncada "startPhantomEntranceEvaluation" contains lots of processes, multi threading processes, background worker, parallel processing with different Pages and Windows.

Comment: @NineBerry there are some places where I am using Dispatcher.Invoke inside "startPhantomEntranceEvaluation" because child pages and windows was freezing. So I use it on another places also.

Comment: @jignesh Only use it at those places and for the shortest time possible. Remove it from around the whole loop body. Try to redesign your code so that you do not directly access the user interface from your business code but have events for updating UI state that your form can subscribe to. And then only use `Dispatcher.Invoke` inside those event handlers in the form itself.

Comment: you should only use Invoke around code that updates the UI. you shouldn't warp the entire thread/processing with it.

Comment: @NineBerry there are total 5 places inside "startPhantomEntranceEvaluation" where I have declare Dispatcher.Invoke. I have set there debugger and check. When loop is starting after that process passing from different conditions and then it will reach to second dispatcher.invoke section. But right now it's not matching our conditions and so second dispatcher.invoke is not running. But still it's freezing. Am I making any wrong logic there ?

Comment: @d.moncada actually I didn't get it. Please can you help me to describe it more ?

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out in the comments, the code you've provided shows that you are actually running the all of the work on the UI thread.

When you call `RunWorkerAsync`, the `BackgroundWorker` starts running the loop, the loop then runs `startPhantomEntranceEvaluation` on the UI thread using `Dispatcher.Invoke`. So all you are doing is calling the background thread to call the UI thread again; none of the actual work is being done in the background.

You need to rework your code so that `Dispatcher.Invoke` is only used if/when you need to update the UI. Alternatively, if you want to stick to the `BackgroundWorker` model, you should use the [`BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress?view=netframework-4.8) method instead of `Dispatcher.Invoke` (provided you don't need the background thread to wait until the UI task completes).

If you need further help on *how* to rework your code, you'll need to post the contents of `startPhantomEntranceEvaluation` at which point I'll be glad to edit my answer to include further guidance.

Comment: Yes you are right that I want to run my all my work under loop which is connected with UI thread. So there are few places where I have use Dispatcher.Invoke where I was getting STA UI related problems. So here I am running while loop with dispatcher.invoke with background worker. So should I use BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress instead of Dispatcher.Invoke ?

Comment: Using `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` vs `Dispatcher.Invoke` is your call. `Dispatcher.Invoke` will pause the background thread and make it wait until whatever you invoked has completed. `ReportProgress` will let your background thread continue while the UI thread processes the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event at the same time.

Comment: but here we have startPhantomEntranceEvaluation contains many sub UI which are also in use for fetch data. Also user can update details from sub UI so I am using Dispatcher.Invoke there also so UI can not be freeze in that case.

Comment: I have apply to create new thread and then apply loop for run all work in loop with reference of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874808/how-to-thread-sleep-in-begininvoke. But I didn't get expected result. Is there any suggestion for me ?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could include code from `startPhantomEntranceEvaluation` in your question. What kind of interaction do you need with the UI? Is it just showing progress/results, or do you expect the user to give input while the loop is running?

Comment: I have try to show you further code of startPhantomEntranceEvaluation by edit my question. So I can explain better to you.

Comment: That was a good start. Next please show in your question which lines from your code need access to the UI thread.

Comment: In deep of `parallelScripts.pExitWithEntrance(phantomEntranceResult);` there is a cs file with thousands of coding lines. And in that different methods and functions are there which is communicating with another or sub level xaml wpf form. So is there any way to show here code. because it's very lengthy code for show here. I don't know about how to show here it.

Comment: Basically, you need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` in the places inside `pExitWithEntrance` that actually interact with the UI, but *only* in those places, not everywhere. This way as much work as possible is done on the background thread. I know there's a lot of code, but I can't help much more without seeing what you're talking about.